# What memory addresses can never point to a valid object

Tags: pointers, memory-address, virtual-memory

I would like to have a set of dummy addresses as flag values that can never be a valid pointer.

For example, if I knew that pointers `0xffff0000` through `0xffffffff` where always invalid I could do something like this in C

```
enum {
    SIZE_TOO_SMALL = 0xffff0001,
    SIZE_TOO_LARGE = 0xffff0002,
    SIZE_EVEN = 0xffff0003,
};

char* allocate_odd_arry(int size) {
    if (size % 2 == 0)
        return SIZE_EVEN;
    if (size < 100)
        return SIZE_TOO_SMALL;
    if (size > 1000)
        return SIZE_TOO_LARGE;
    return malloc(size);
}
```

A silly example, but potentially powerful since it removes the need of sending an extra flag variable. One way I could do this is to allocate a few bytes myself and use those addresses as flags, but that comes with a small memory cost for each unique flag I use.

I don't expect a portable solution, but is there any guarantee on windows, linux, macos, that the addressable space will not include certain values?

Comment: You save a flag, but you're still having to check if the result is good or not somehow.  At best, this feels leaky since if you add more error values, existing code could silently treat them as valid.

Comment: @StephenNewell My main motivation was thinking about implementation of a language (in particular [pony](ponylang.io)) which has "primitives" which are completely stateless so don't need an actual referent. If baked into the language a leak like this would be impossible to leak. I'm still not sure how the primitives are implemented, but I'm just wondering whether it would be possible to implement them like this.

Comment: And yes, the primary savings here is the cost of returning an additional variable, not the cost of checking said variable.

Answer (score 1):

For windows I have found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/virtual-address-spaces) which says that on 32 bits systems the virtual address space is `0x00000000` to `0x7fffffff`, and for 64 bit systems it is `0x0000000000000000` to `0x00007fffffffffff`. I am not sure if other addresses have any reserved meaning, but they ought to be safe for this use case.

Looking at Linux the answer seems a bit more complicated because (like everything else in linux) it is configurable. [This answer on unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509607/how-a-64-bit-process-virtual-address-space-is-divided-in-linux) shows how memory is divided between the kernel and user space. `0000_8000_0000_0000` to `ffff_7fff_ffff_ffff` is listed as non canonical, which I think means it should never be used. Though really the kernel space (`ffff_8000_0000_0000`  to `ffff_ffff_ffff_ffff`) seems like it ought to be safe to use as well, but I'm less sure if there could never be a system function that returns such a pointer.

On Mac OS I've found [this article](https://flylib.com/books/en/3.126.1.91/1/) which puts the virtual memory range as
`0` to `0x0007_FFFF_FFFF_F000` (64 bit) or `0` to `0xFFFF_F000` (32 bit), so outside of these ranges would be fine.

Seems there is a little bit of overlap between all of the unused regions, so if you wanted to target all three platforms with the same address it would be possible. I'm still not 100% confident that these addresses are really truly safe to use on the respective OS, so I'm still holding out for anyone more knowledgeable to chime in.